# How to install jenkins in centos with firefox?

Tags: jenkins, installation, centos

I have installed jenkins in windows and used.. 
But now I want to know how to install it in Centos (linux). With web browser (firefox) I downloaded jenkins.war file and saved that file in my home directory.. Now how should I install Jenkins and open it in firefox in Centos..

Plz let me know step by step procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install a Tomcat server and put the war file in its "deploy" directory.
Or, you can follow [the official documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions)